# PHP form not sending emails while collecting IP Address

Tags: php, ip-address, contact-form

My code in HTML:

```
<form action="submit.php" id="form" class="sk-form" method="post">
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lasttname" value="" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<input type="hidden" id="ipadd" name="ipadd" value="<?=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?>" />
<div class="text-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn bdr6 sksubmit">SUBMIT NOW</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is the submit.php

```
<?php


function sMail($To,$From,$Sbj,$Str,$Cc,$Bcc){
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$From."\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: ".$Cc."\r\n";
$headers .= "bCc: ".$Bcc."\r\n";


mail($To, $Sbj, $Str, $headers);
}
$recnumbr = rand(1,999);
$Str = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
<td>Inquiry Details</font></strong></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>First Name:</strong></font>/td>
<td>'.$_REQUEST["firstname"].'</font>/td></tr>
<tr>
<td><strong> Last Name:</strong></font></td>
<td>'.$_REQUEST["lastname"].'</font></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><strong> IP ADDRESS:</strong></font></td>
<td>'.$_REQUEST["ipadd"].'</font></td></tr>
</table>';

$Str2 = '<table width="96%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td colspan="2" valign="middle" style="padding-left:10px;" valign="top" class="readmore-testi">
    <p>Thank You for submit your details. We will contact you ASAP...!</p></td></tr>
</table>';

sMail("myemail@gmail.com","Inquiry Details<info@same-hosted-website.com>","Inquiry Request - same-hosted-website.com".$Company,$Str,"","");
sMail($_REQUEST["email"],"Inquiry Request Submit <info@same-hosted-website.com>","Inquiry Request - same-hosted-website.com".$Company,$Str2,"","");


header ("location:thank-you.php");


?>
```

The problem is when I tried to capture IP via submit.php my form didn't send me email, and it work fine without this on submit.php:

```
.$_REQUEST["ipadd"].
```

When any user land on the main HTML page, then in view-source form capture the IP address properly. But the problem is my form didn't work while sending IP to my email. And without IP it is sending emails properly and quickly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `$_REQUEST["email"]` there is no field called `email` in your form!

Comment: And what sense does capturing the specified ip address make at all?

Answer (score 0):

You missed semicolon `;`

```
value="<?=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>"
```

Comment: problem is in my submit.php ... my input code is working fine and getting IP address properly but when it passed to submit.php then it didn't send me email... and when i remove the IP value in submit.php then i get email properly and quickly ...

Comment: The semi-colon is not necessary for a single statement in PHP - `"<?= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>` is perfectly valid.

Comment: exactly .. it is working fine without semi-colon ... i can check that code is capturing IP in view-source ... but when it went to submit.php it don't send e-mail to my ID ... you can test my Code (HTML + Submit.php) then you will know the issue ... 
i just want a fix for submit.php so that i can get the IP as well ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo the following, It will be blank untill you don't `echo`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ipadd" name="ipadd" value="<?php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>" />
```

Like

```
<input type="hidden" id="ipadd" name="ipadd" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>" />
```

and 2nd thing:

there are no field with the name of `email` which you are using on next page.

Comment: problem is in my submit.php ... my input code is working fine and getting IP address properly but when it passed to submit.php then it didn't send me email... and when i remove the IP value in submit.php then i get email properly and quickly ...

Comment: Everything working fine. There are some typo issues that you have to change. Like `lasttname` to `lastname` in your form. there are no input field for email, but you are using `$_REQUEST['email']` in your `submit.php`. So you should add a `<input type="email" name="email" />` in your form.

Comment: can you test it with the correction you told ... because i test and result is the same .. with    '.$_REQUEST["ipadd"].' in submit.php not respond correctly.

Comment: What did you get after changes?

Comment: same ... no e-mail with '.$_REQUEST["ipadd"].'  ... but if i remove '.$_REQUEST["ipadd"].' in submit.php then i get email very quickly ...